# Is it possible to package many peer class by one pom.xml?

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, aws-lambda, maven-2, maven-3

The problem is I has many peer class without a root class (or parent) but i want to have only one pom.xml file for them and I want to be able to create a .jar file for each of them independently. Is it even possible? I've read about multi-model and agregation, but I don't like these sollutions. I've try achive this by use many execution tags, but in this case all classes package by one single click (I want to separate it). Maybe do you have some advices for me.

Comment: Why do you like to create different jar files? Sounds like you want to separate them..on the other hand you wrote: ` I've read about multi-model and agregation, but I don't like these sollutions` ? Why don't you like that?

Comment: @khmarbaise I don't have parent class which is needed to multi-model or aggregation. This is like many tiny projects which one i want to connect in one. I just creating lambdas on aws. It is possible that I am approaching the problem wrong and it should be done in a completely different way.

Comment: If you like to have separate jar files I recommend to create a multi module build...that's the ways...